# Use the definition of limit to prove $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x^2-1}=-1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

Given $\epsilon>0$ and $0<\delta\leq\min\{1,\sqrt{\epsilon}\}\,$, we have that $\,|x|<\delta\implies0<x^2<1\implies0<\left|\frac{1}{x^2-1}\right|<1$, thus
$$\left|\frac{1}{x^2-1}+1
\right|=\left|\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{x^2-1}
\right|\cdot|x|^2<1\cdot\left(\sqrt{\epsilon}\right)^2=\epsilon.$$

Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  If $0<x^2<1$ then $-1<x^2-1<0$ so
$$\frac1{x^2-1}<-1$$
so
$$\Bigl|\frac1{x^2-1}\Bigr|>1\ .$$
You will need to revise your inequalities (and probably also your choice of $\delta\,$).

Other small points: you should say
$$\delta=\langle\hbox{something}\rangle\quad\hbox{and}\quad 0<|x|<\delta\ ,$$
not $\delta\le\cdots$ and $|x|<\delta$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion. How about $\delta=\min\{1/\sqrt{2},\sqrt{\epsilon/2}\}$? This would imply that $$|x|<1/\sqrt2\implies\frac{1}{|x^2-1|}<2.$$

Also, do you have any suggestion on how to spot the correct values of $\delta$, or does this intuition come with practice? On most cases $\delta<1$ works, but on cases like these ones, we need to restrict $\delta$ a bit more. In a few words, is there a trick to spotting the correct $\delta$ on the first try?

Comment: Looks good.$\,$

Comment: In this case if you allow $x$ to be close to $1$ then $\frac1{x^2-1}$ can be arbitrarily large.  So this would not seem to be a promising approach.